# Relative virtual path is not allowed when using server.MapPath()

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, web-config, global-asax

I am Trying to get the configuration file using the following code:

```
public void EncryptConnString()
        {
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"/"));
            ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
            if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
            {               
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            }
        }
```

But i am getting the error

> The relative virtual path 'F:/xxxx/yyyy/sample/' is not allowed here.

Note: I am accessing this code in `global.asax` page What i am doing wrong?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/")

Comment: Sorry, getting the same error!

Comment: Note: I am accessing this code in global.asax, if i call the same in page method means its works filne

Comment: updated the page method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass null to this method, it will return the root config file for you:

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
```